# Returning Actionresult<IEnumerable<T>> with proper Http Code with GET

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I was thinking about how properly handle return code with collections

If you have a single value (POCO/Model) - no issues, if sometimes you need to return `Http-204`. For example, during logon. You just do

```cs
if (model == null)
    return NoContent();
return Ok(model);
```

I came across this article --https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Feb/24/Null-API-Responses-and-HTTP-204-Results-in-ASPNET-Core

Lets say, you have a system where for collections the "provider" always returns non-materialized `IEnumerable<T>`. And at the point of `return Ok(result)` I don't know if there is any content. The only way to know is to call `.ToList()`, get `Count` and make decision on that. This is when I want to handle a valid empty result as `Http-204` code

I understand, that position of the author in the article is that an empty collection is still should return `200`.
Is this generally accepted behavior or an opinion?
Otherwise it seem that as long as I don't have `null` coming out from `provider.Get(..)` call, I am safe to return properly formatted (application/json) '200' response.

Are there any performance implication issues when I need to know ahead the item count and if I materialize `IEnumerable<T>` by calling `ToList()` prior to return `Ok` or `NoContent`?

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents are:

1. As long it's clear to the consumer of the API it's OK.
2. I don't believe there is an agreed industry standards for this.
3. This becomes even more nuanced with `IAsyncEnumerable`.

### More

> Are there any performance implication issues when I need to know ahead the item count and if I materialize `IEnumerable<T>` by calling `ToList()` prior to return Ok or NoContent?

I don't think there is a general answer to this. It depends how you implement it. For example, if you `result.ToList().Count()` to check if to return 204 and then return `result` the work could be done twice.

---

> The only way to know is to call .ToList(), get Count and make decision on that.

It's worth pointing out that there is `Any()`. It doesn't mean you should use it because what `Any` does depends on the source of the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: *"... if to return 204 and then return result the work could be done twice."*, absolutely. I wouldn't return the IEnumerable result, if I materialize it. I would return the resulting list. And, yes, I can use `Any` against the list, or `Count` property of the list, which will not cause double execution if I call method `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` .. Back to that list return. When asp.net executes your action method it gets `ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>`. It materializes it by iterating it by json serializer, I don't imagine anything malicious I can do if I materialize myself. But I didn't reflect